# Unable to disable touchpad on HP ProBook 4520s running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

The touchpad on HP ProBook 4520s is just too sensitive. Is it possible to disable this on Windows 7.

Comment: Be more specific then it would be possible for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

From this HP hardware reference guide, "To turn the TouchPad on and off, quickly double-tap the TouchPad off indicator. When the TouchPad off indicator is amber, the TouchPad is off."

[image]

Here's the [direct link to the PDF](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/CoreRedirect.jsp?redirectReason=DocIndexPDF&prodSeriesId=4145198&targetPage=http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02468666/c02468666.pdf).

Comment: So it really is that easy...

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to control panel>Mouse and in advance tab Device Settings. And disable the touchpad. I think it's what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @avirk! I just realized that the Synaptics driver was not installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the default drivers (I think from 2006) you have to update your driver for the mouse first, and then it will work with double click.

It doesn't work with the old (default) drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the mouse moves too fast when it is being used? Try Control Panel > Mouse > Pointer Options and drag the top pointer down to "Slow".

If you do actually want to disable it go to Device Manager, scroll down to "Mouse and other pointing devices", right-click on the touchpad and choose "Disable".

[image]

If this doesn't work, or is not what you're after, considering actually disconnecting the touchpad (probably requires removal of the keyboard).

Comment: if mouse run very quickly then its speed can be reduce through Control Panel>mouse in windows 7. I'm pretty sure that this is not what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the notification area (low right hand corner), you'll probably find an icon that either looks like a little touchpad (square with two buttons above it) or perhaps like a cursive O on a red background.

Right click that, and pull up the settings.  Oftentimes, disabling the "tap to click" function makes it a lot less erratic, but you can control the acceleration, the "pinch to zoom" functions from there, too.